# Fatal error: Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php on line 89

Tags: magento

I had installed an custom extension. Its running successfully and had all files at its place. But I am getting this error on my listing page

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/unisport_com/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php on line 89.
```

I google this error but did'nt found any proper solution. One solution is to copy the original Abstract.php file may be because extension had overwrite this file. But I checked the code from the backup its the same and also copied original file but nothing worked for me.

What is wrong with this file? Can anybody help?

below is the code of Abstract.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Sales
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Quote item abstract model
 *
 * Price attributes:
 *  - price - initial item price, declared during product association
 *  - original_price - product price before any calculations
 *  - calculation_price - prices for item totals calculation
 *  - custom_price - new price that can be declared by user and recalculated during calculation process
 *  - original_custom_price - original defined value of custom price without any convertion
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Sales
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
abstract class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    implements Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Interface
{
    /**
     * Parent item for sub items for bundle product, configurable product, etc.
     *
     * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    protected $_parentItem  = null;

    /**
     * Children items in bundle product, configurable product, etc.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_children    = array();

    /**
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messages    = array();

    /**
     * Retrieve Quote instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    abstract function getQuote();

    /**
     * Retrieve product model object associated with item
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        $product = $this->_getData('product');
        if ($product === null && $this->getProductId()) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId())
                ->load($this->getProductId());
            $this->setProduct($product);
        }

        /**
         * Reset product final price because it related to custom options
         */
        $product->setFinalPrice(null);
        if (is_array($this->_optionsByCode)) {
            $product->setCustomOptions($this->_optionsByCode);
        }
        return $product;
    }

    /**
     * Returns special download params (if needed) for custom option with type = 'file'
     * Needed to implement Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Interface.
     * Return null, as quote item needs no additional configuration.
     *
     * @return null|Varien_Object
     */
    public function getFileDownloadParams()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Specify parent item id before saving data
     *
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();
        if ($this->getParentItem()) {
            $this->setParentItemId($this->getParentItem()->getId());
        }
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Set parent item
     *
     * @param  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $parentItem
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
     */
    public function setParentItem($parentItem)
    {
        if ($parentItem) {
            $this->_parentItem = $parentItem;
            $parentItem->addChild($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent item
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
     */
    public function getParentItem()
    {
        return $this->_parentItem;
    }

    /**
     * Get chil items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->_children;
    }

    /**
     * Add child item
     *
     * @param  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $child
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function addChild($child)
    {
        $this->setHasChildren(true);
        $this->_children[] = $child;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Adds message(s) for quote item. Duplicated messages are not added.
     *
     * @param  mixed $messages
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function setMessage($messages)
    {
        $messagesExists = $this->getMessage(false);
        if (!is_array($messages)) {
            $messages = array($messages);
        }
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            if (!in_array($message, $messagesExists)) {
                $this->addMessage($message);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add message of quote item to array of messages
     *
     * @param   string $message
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function addMessage($message)
    {
        $this->_messages[] = $message;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get messages array of quote item
     *
     * @param   bool $string flag for converting messages to string
     * @return  array|string
     */
    public function getMessage($string = true)
    {
        if ($string) {
            return join("\n", $this->_messages);
        }
        return $this->_messages;
    }

    /**
     * Removes message by text
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function removeMessageByText($text)
    {
        foreach ($this->_messages as $key => $message) {
            if ($message == $text) {
                unset($this->_messages[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Clears all messages
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function clearMessage()
    {
        $this->unsMessage(); // For older compatibility, when we kept message inside data array
        $this->_messages = array();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve store model object
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->getQuote()->getStore();
    }

    /**
     * Checking item data
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function checkData()
    {
        $this->setHasError(false);
        $this->clearMessage();

        $qty = $this->_getData('qty');

        try {
            $this->setQty($qty);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->setHasError(true);
            $this->setMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->setHasError(true);
            $this->setMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Item qty declaration error.'));
        }

        try {
            $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->checkProductBuyState($this->getProduct());
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->getQuote()->setHasError(true)
                ->addMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Some of the products below do not have all the required options.'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Item options declaration error.'));
            $this->getQuote()->setHasError(true)
                ->addMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Items options declaration error.'));
        }

        if ($this->getProduct()->getHasError()) {
            $this->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Some of the selected options are not currently available.'));
            $this->getQuote()->setHasError(true)
                ->addMessage($this->getProduct()->getMessage(), 'options');
        }

        if ($this->getHasConfigurationUnavailableError()) {
            $this->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Selected option(s) or their combination is not currently available.'));
            $this->getQuote()->setHasError(true)
                ->addMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Some item options or their combination are not currently available.'), 'unavailable-configuration');
            $this->unsHasConfigurationUnavailableError();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get original (not related with parent item) item quantity
     *
     * @return  int|float
     */
    public function getQty()
    {
        return $this->_getData('qty');
    }

    /**
     * Get total item quantity (include parent item relation)
     *
     * @return  int|float
     */
    public function getTotalQty()
    {
        if ($this->getParentItem()) {
            return $this->getQty()*$this->getParentItem()->getQty();
        }
        return $this->getQty();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate item row total price
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
     */
    public function calcRowTotal()
    {
        $qty        = $this->getTotalQty();
        // Round unit price before multiplying to prevent losing 1 cent on subtotal
        $total      = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty;
        $baseTotal  = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty;

        $this->setRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($total));
        $this->setBaseRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($baseTotal));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get item price used for quote calculation process.
     * This method get custom price (if it is defined) or original product final price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCalculationPrice()
    {
        $price = $this->_getData('calculation_price');
        if (is_null($price)) {
            if ($this->hasCustomPrice()) {
                $price = $this->getCustomPrice();
            } else {
                $price = $this->getConvertedPrice();
            }
            $this->setData('calculation_price', $price);
        }
        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Get item price used for quote calculation process.
     * This method get original custom price applied before tax calculation
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCalculationPriceOriginal()
    {
        $price = $this->_getData('calculation_price');
        if (is_null($price)) {
            if ($this->hasOriginalCustomPrice()) {
                $price = $this->getOriginalCustomPrice();
            } else {
                $price = $this->getConvertedPrice();
            }
            $this->setData('calculation_price', $price);
        }
        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Get calculation price used for quote calculation in base currency.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBaseCalculationPrice()
    {
        if (!$this->hasBaseCalculationPrice()) {
            if ($this->hasCustomPrice()) {
                $price = (float) $this->getCustomPrice();
                if ($price) {
                    $rate = $this->getStore()->convertPrice($price) / $price;
                    $price = $price / $rate;
                }
            } else {
                $price = $this->getPrice();
            }
            $this->setBaseCalculationPrice($price);
        }
        return $this->_getData('base_calculation_price');
    }

    /**
     * Get original calculation price used for quote calculation in base currency.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal()
    {
        if (!$this->hasBaseCalculationPrice()) {
            if ($this->hasOriginalCustomPrice()) {
                $price = (float) $this->getOriginalCustomPrice();
                if ($price) {
                    $rate = $this->getStore()->convertPrice($price) / $price;
                    $price = $price / $rate;
                }
            } else {
                $price = $this->getPrice();
            }
            $this->setBaseCalculationPrice($price);
        }
        return $this->_getData('base_calculation_price');
    }

    /**
     * Get whether the item is nominal
     * TODO: fix for multishipping checkout
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isNominal()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('is_nominal')) {
            $this->setData('is_nominal', $this->getProduct() ? '1' == $this->getProduct()->getIsRecurring() : false);
        }
        return $this->_getData('is_nominal');
    }

    /**
     * Data getter for 'is_nominal'
     * Used for converting item to order item
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIsNominal()
    {
        return (int)$this->isNominal();
    }

    /**
     * Get original price (retrieved from product) for item.
     * Original price value is in quote selected currency
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getOriginalPrice()
    {
        $price = $this->_getData('original_price');
        if (is_null($price)) {
            $price = $this->getStore()->convertPrice($this->getBaseOriginalPrice());
            $this->setData('original_price', $price);
        }
        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Set original price to item (calculation price will be refreshed too)
     *
     * @param   float $price
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function setOriginalPrice($price)
    {
        return $this->setData('original_price', $price);
    }

    /**
     * Get Original item price (got from product) in base website currency
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBaseOriginalPrice()
    {
        return $this->_getData('base_original_price');
    }

    /**
     * Specify custom item price (used in case whe we have apply not product price to item)
     *
     * @param   float $value
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function setCustomPrice($value)
    {
        $this->setCalculationPrice($value);
        $this->setBaseCalculationPrice(null);
        return $this->setData('custom_price', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get item price. Item price currency is website base currency.
     *
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->_getData('price');
    }

    /**
     * Specify item price (base calculation price and converted price will be refreshed too)
     *
     * @param   float $value
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function setPrice($value)
    {
        $this->setBaseCalculationPrice(null);
        $this->setConvertedPrice(null);
        return $this->setData('price', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get item price converted to quote currency
     * @return float
     */
    public function getConvertedPrice()
    {
        $price = $this->_getData('converted_price');
        if (is_null($price)) {
            $price = $this->getStore()->convertPrice($this->getPrice());
            $this->setData('converted_price', $price);
        }
        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Set new value for converted price
     * @param float $value
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract
     */
    public function setConvertedPrice($value)
    {
        $this->setCalculationPrice(null);
        $this->setData('converted_price', $value);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Clone quote item
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
     */
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->setId(null);
        $this->_parentItem  = null;
        $this->_children    = array();
        $this->_messages    = array();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Checking if there children calculated or parent item
     * when we have parent quote item and its children
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isChildrenCalculated()
    {
        if ($this->getParentItem()) {
            $calculate = $this->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getPriceType();
        } else {
            $calculate = $this->getProduct()->getPriceType();
        }

        if ((null !== $calculate) && (int)$calculate === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::CALCULATE_CHILD) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checking can we ship product separatelly (each child separately)
     * or each parent product item can be shipped only like one item
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShipSeparately()
    {
        if ($this->getParentItem()) {
            $shipmentType = $this->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getShipmentType();
        } else {
            $shipmentType = $this->getProduct()->getShipmentType();
        }

        if ((null !== $shipmentType) &&
            (int)$shipmentType === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::SHIPMENT_SEPARATELY) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }





















    /**
     * Calculate item tax amount
     *
     * @deprecated logic moved to tax totals calculation model
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
     */
    public function calcTaxAmount()
    {
        $store = $this->getStore();

        if (!Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax($store)) {
            if (Mage::helper('tax')->applyTaxAfterDiscount($store)) {
                $rowTotal       = $this->getRowTotalWithDiscount();
                $rowBaseTotal   = $this->getBaseRowTotalWithDiscount();
            } else {
                $rowTotal       = $this->getRowTotal();
                $rowBaseTotal   = $this->getBaseRowTotal();
            }

            $taxPercent = $this->getTaxPercent()/100;

            $this->setTaxAmount($store->roundPrice($rowTotal * $taxPercent));
            $this->setBaseTaxAmount($store->roundPrice($rowBaseTotal * $taxPercent));

            $rowTotal       = $this->getRowTotal();
            $rowBaseTotal   = $this->getBaseRowTotal();
            $this->setTaxBeforeDiscount($store->roundPrice($rowTotal * $taxPercent));
            $this->setBaseTaxBeforeDiscount($store->roundPrice($rowBaseTotal * $taxPercent));
        } else {
            if (Mage::helper('tax')->applyTaxAfterDiscount($store)) {
                $totalBaseTax = $this->getBaseTaxAmount();
                $totalTax = $this->getTaxAmount();

                if ($totalTax && $totalBaseTax) {
                    $totalTax -= $this->getDiscountAmount() * ($this->getTaxPercent() / 100);
                    $totalBaseTax -= $this->getBaseDiscountAmount() * ($this->getTaxPercent() / 100);

                    $this->setBaseTaxAmount($store->roundPrice($totalBaseTax));
                    $this->setTaxAmount($store->roundPrice($totalTax));
                }
            }
        }

        if (Mage::helper('tax')->discountTax($store) && !Mage::helper('tax')->applyTaxAfterDiscount($store)) {
            if ($this->getDiscountPercent()) {
                $baseTaxAmount =  $this->getBaseTaxBeforeDiscount();
                $taxAmount = $this->getTaxBeforeDiscount();

                $baseDiscountDisposition = $baseTaxAmount/100*$this->getDiscountPercent();
                $discountDisposition = $taxAmount/100*$this->getDiscountPercent();

                $this->setDiscountAmount($this->getDiscountAmount()+$discountDisposition);
                $this->setBaseDiscountAmount($this->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$baseDiscountDisposition);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get item tax amount
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return  decimal
     */
    public function getTaxAmount()
    {
        return $this->_getData('tax_amount');
    }


    /**
     * Get item base tax amount
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getBaseTaxAmount()
    {
        return $this->_getData('base_tax_amount');
    }

    /**
     * Get item price (item price always exclude price)
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return decimal
     */
    protected function _calculatePrice($value, $saveTaxes = true)
    {
        $store = $this->getQuote()->getStore();

        if (Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax($store)) {
            $bAddress = $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
            $sAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

            $address = $this->getAddress();

            if ($address) {
                switch ($address->getAddressType()) {
                    case Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING:
                        $bAddress = $address;
                        break;
                    case Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING:
                        $sAddress = $address;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if ($this->getProduct()->getIsVirtual()) {
                $sAddress = $bAddress;
            }

            $priceExcludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice(
                $this->getProduct()->setTaxPercent(null),
                $value,
                false,
                $sAddress,
                $bAddress,
                $this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
                $store
            );

            $priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice(
                $this->getProduct()->setTaxPercent(null),
                $value,
                true,
                $sAddress,
                $bAddress,
                $this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
                $store
            );

            if ($saveTaxes) {
                $qty = $this->getQty();
                if ($this->getParentItem()) {
                    $qty = $qty*$this->getParentItem()->getQty();
                }

                if (Mage::helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax($store)) {
                    $rowTotal = $value*$qty;
                    $rowTotalExcTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice(
                        $this->getProduct()->setTaxPercent(null),
                        $rowTotal,
                        false,
                        $sAddress,
                        $bAddress,
                        $this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
                        $store
                    );
                    $rowTotalIncTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice(
                        $this->getProduct()->setTaxPercent(null),
                        $rowTotal,
                        true,
                        $sAddress,
                        $bAddress,
                        $this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
                        $store
                    );
                    $totalBaseTax = $rowTotalIncTax-$rowTotalExcTax;
                    $this->setRowTotalExcTax($rowTotalExcTax);
                }
                else {
                    $taxAmount = $priceIncludingTax - $priceExcludingTax;
                    $this->setTaxPercent($this->getProduct()->getTaxPercent());
                    $totalBaseTax = $taxAmount*$qty;
                }

                $totalTax = $this->getStore()->convertPrice($totalBaseTax);
                $this->setTaxBeforeDiscount($totalTax);
                $this->setBaseTaxBeforeDiscount($totalBaseTax);

                $this->setTaxAmount($totalTax);
                $this->setBaseTaxAmount($totalBaseTax);
            }

            $value = $priceExcludingTax;
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is not in core files.Your module is setting some quote price that creating issue.check your model files

Comment: ok thanks Mahmood for your reply. I will my model files